# "No operating system found” when CD Drive is selected as first boot option

Tags: windows-10, bios

I have a Gigabyte GA-Z77X-UP4 TH. BIOS version f9. The way I used to work is have my BD DRIVE be the first bootable option in case I need to boot from a live cd. (Yes, I know you can use F12 to select a boot device but I prefer to have it set in the boot options) The way it's supposed to work is, BIOS should first try to boot from Option 1 (the bd drive) and if there is no inserted disk, it would go to option 2 (Windows Boot Manager) and Windows would boot. Yes, this adds a few seconds to the boot time but I don't care.

The problem is that now, when I select the BD Drive to be boot option 1, I get an error on boot that no operating system was found. This shouldn't be happening; it should be booting from option 2 (Windows) when no CD is inserted.

I can't know what caused this since its been a very long time since I've used CD as the first boot option (few years.)

Comment: Which computer model and BIOS version? What has changed lately?

Comment: Oh, sorry! I updated my question with the required info.

Comment: Why do you keep writing BD drive when you mean CD drive or DVD drive?  And have you tried Different bootable CDs/DVDs?

Comment: I wrote BD because my drive is a Blu-Ray burner. It doesn't matter though, it's the same thing for my issue. What do you mean did I try with different disks? If I put a disk in it boots into the disk fine. The issue if there is NO disk, it won't boot into windows.

Comment: What has changed, Windows update or anything?

Comment: Last time I had CD\DVD set as first boot option must have been 5-6 years ago. Since then only thing that changed is that I upgraded from Windows 7 to 10. Still same computer.